# Remix debugger ignores breakpoint

Tags: remix, dapp-debugging

## Description of issue

I'm trying to debug a simple contract using remix on chrome v. 65 on Ubuntu.

I must be doing something wrong, because I have the following issue:

When I place a breakpoint in the middle of a function, execute the function and then hit "DEBUG", the debugger is not at the breakpoint.

Furthermore, when I hit the button "Jump to next breakpoint" it (the execution flow slider) merely jumps to the end.

## The contract

The simple contract compiles and remix looks like so after compilation:
[image]

## Deployment

Then I deploy the contract, after which remix looks like so:
[image]

## Set breakpoint in a function and run that

Then I set a breakpoint on line 18, enter the value 15 as argument to the function `changeValue` and execute it, after which remix looks like so:
[image]

## Hit "DEBUG" and notice that program is not at the breakpoint

After hitting "DEBUG" I would expect the program to be at the breakpoint and a highlight therearound in the code. In staed I see this:
[image]

## Hitting "Jump to next breakpoint" ends

When I now hit "Jump to next breakpoint" I'd expect the debugger to hit the breakpoint after all, in stead it jumps to the execution end (as you can see from the slider position).

This is what remix looks like after hitting "Jump to next breakpoint":
[image]

## Question

What am I doing wrong or what else should I try?

Comment: Mabe you have a browser extension active, that blocks certain javascript execution. (e.g. Adblocks)

Comment: Old issue, probably already fixed

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: I had it recently